# How to add an element to an array?

Tags: java, string, null

Suppose I need to add an element to my `array1`. The approach I took was to copy `array1` into `array2` using a `for loop`, than delete `array1`, and re-declare `array1`, with one more element than the previous `array1`. And than copy `array2` into `array1`, and than initialize the new element in `array1`. But I am guessing there is no way to delete an `array`, so how can I add an element to an `array` after its declaration.

Comment: You can't "delete" variables (but they can go out of scope). And you don't want to change the type of a variable, even if you could.  Your question smells of being an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a completely different approach. Better that you tell us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: Also you're confusing variable with the value or reference that it holds.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels let me re-word my question..

Comment: Yes, please do!

Comment: Java doesn't work like that. Give it a different name.

Comment: And please show a real world example of what you mean.

Comment: Also, Java naming convention is for variables to be mixed-case, with leading lower-case letter, so your variable should be `name`, not `NAME`. Unless it's a *constant*, but that seems unlikely.

Comment: You've completely changed your question. If you want to ask something else, close this question and ask a new one.

Comment: And in answer to your new question, look at Java's `ArrayList`.

Comment: This is now a totally different question -- please stop wasting folks time with this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you have naming conflicts, the best solution is to use a more descriptive variable name.

In your case, use `nameOfThing1` or `nameOfThing2` in order to distinguish them. In most cases though, when something's "name" is a number, it's usually called an "id".

Depending on the situation, another strategy is to restructure your code, so that the variables aren't in scope at the same time. You can declare a block using `{ }` in order to make a separate scope for each variable.

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose i have an int named NAME, and I need to delete it, to make a String with the same name. Will NAME = null delete the int??

No.  It will give you a compilation error.

> If it won't, then how can you delete a variable?

You can't.  Variables cannot be deleted.

(Aside: Java's static typing would break if it was possible to change the binding between a variable's name and its declared type.  If you (actually) deleted the original variable, that wouldn't be so bad, but it would be bad for readability.  Anyhow ... you can't.)

One solution is to declare a different variable with a different variable name.  Using better variable names will help.

Alternatively, you could use block scoping to manage the scope / lifetime of a (local) variable.  For example:

```
public void doIt() {
    int a = 1;
    {
       String a = "hey";  // compilation error
       int b = 2;
    }
    String b = "bee";     // OK
}
```

Note you can only do this with local variables.

---

If you are worried about the "efficiency overheads" of having multiple variables at the same time, don't.  If there is a significant efficiency concern, the JIT compiler should be able to deal with it.  (If not now, then in a future Java release.)